# Create contact sheet in PaintShop Pro X7?

Tags: transparency, png, corel-paint-shop-pro

Is it possible to create a contact sheet based on multiple images in PaintShop Pro X7? Is it possible to do this while retaining the sources' alpha channels?

Answer (score -1):

I created a folder containing 9 images.
I named them sequentially 1.jpg through 9.jpg
I wanted image 5.jpg to be the center of what I was doing.
I created a script to create a large file to place these into.
I then copied each of the 9 source files into the new files making a grid 3 x 3.
I then saved this script.

As long as I have all names the same, I guess it works.

Note: This was first part of an exercise to create a Christmas ball where I took the output from this, merged all layers, use effects / geometric / circle and effects / geometric / spherize.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you show that script?